# JSON literals and Javascript objects. I am confused

Tags: javascript, json

Let's consider this code:

```
(function(){
    var a = {"id": "1", "name": "mike", "lastname": "ross"};
    var b = JSON.parse('{"id": "1", "name": "mike", "lastname": "ross"}');
    var c = Object.create({"id": "1", "name": "mike", "lastname": "ross"});

    document.write(typeof(a) + "</br>");
    document.write(typeof(b) + "</br>");
    document.write(typeof(c) + "</br>");
})();​
```

**Questions**

1. Which are the differences between the three assignments?
2. Do the objects a, b and c exactly overlap?
3. If yes, why? If no, why?

Please add references to your answers.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WzZcG/2/).

Comment: a, b and c are different Object with same key value pair. a== b will be false. they are at different locations in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` and `b` are effectively identical (they have the same properties, with the same values, in the same places). `c` is completely different.  You can see a clear difference if you log the objects to the console instead of printing limited info to the page:

[image]

`c` is the one on the right. It's created an object with no own properties. The properties you specified are actually on the `prototype` of `c`. The reason for this is that the first argument to [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is the `prototype` of the object to be created.

Note that you *could* use `Object.create` to get the same effect - just pass `Object.prototype` as the first argument:

```
var d = Object.create(Object.prototype, { 
    "id": { "value": 1 }, //values are 'property descriptors'
    "name": { "value": "mike" }
    //etc...
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`a` and `b` result in "indentical" objects (in the same way that `{a:1}` abd `{a:1}` are identical).

`JSON.parse` parses the input JSON *string*, and outputs the parsed value. In this case, an object.

`c` is different. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates a new object with the prototype set to the first argument. You can verify that `c.__proto__.id` is equal to `1` (and unavailable in the first two cases).

At the first sight, all of the three methods result in the "same" object: Reading the property `id` gives `1` in all cases. In the third case, this result is caused by prototype inheritance. This offers a possible **feature**:

```
var x = Object.create({id:1});
x.id = NaN;
console.log(x.id);
// NaN
delete x.id;
console.log(x.id);
// 1 - The old value is back :)
// ( for x = {id: 1};, the old value would be gone! )
```